# Xamarin parse string to URI replaces %20 with a space

Tags: string, parsing, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uri

I am trying to pass in the Uri of an Image into an UriImageSource.Uri but within the Uri String is contained %20 which gets erroneously converted into white space

i.e.

```
http://domain.co.uk/Category%20Name/Products/Product-image.jpg
```

When this gets parsed through to my function

```
    UriImageSource UriImageSource = new UriImageSource();

        UriBuilder Builder = new UriBuilder(productURL);
        UriImageSource.Uri = Builder.Uri;
        return UriImageSource;
```

the UriImageSource.Uri gets converted to

```
http://domain.co.uk/Category Name/Products/Product-image.jpg
```

This then is throwing an error in my application because the URL contains %20 rather than white space... Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: %20 == 32, which is the "space" character.  Those requests should be equivalent

Comment: Sorted out the error now, thanks Jason and @idenardi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encode/decode url using HttpUtility class from System.Web

More information about this class you can find here
[HttpUtility doc](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Web.HttpUtility/)